# Is it possible to limit the number of records queried?

Tags: sql, sql-server

For the purpose of this question, the results or accuracy thereof are irrelevant. I just want to know if it is possible to query, say, the first 1000 rows of a table. This may only produce 100 results or it may return 1000. I do not want to explicitly limit the results, only the number of rows queried.

Comment: `SELECT TOP 100 * FROM table`

Comment: No, that limits the results.  Right?

Comment: You are 2.5K user. Why deleting the previous question and adding another. You know you can always edit and clarify.

Comment: Well, of course, that's what you want. Or `SELECT * FROM (SELECT TOP 100 * FROM table) AS A.....` instead

Comment: I deleted the other question because it was a significant edit and it had already become a garbage dump of misunderstanding (whether on my part or not I cannot say)

Comment: So "First" has no concept in a database. Data exists in sets. Sets have no ordering until you apply one.

Comment: Okay that's the most useful answer so far... thank you.

Comment: @ScottBeeson What is it that you want?. If you want to use a query and limit the rows from the table then just use the `SELECT TOP 100 * FROM table` as a derived table as I posted on another comment

Comment: Also you have not provided the sample query. If it's a simple query from one table, ok. If it's more complicated, with joins and subqueries and derived tables, then "searching only 1000 rows" makes not much sense.

Comment: @Lamak Yes, I see now, your nested statement will work for my intended use.  Thank you.

Comment: Can you explain more about your intended use case?

Comment: @Lamak it worked very well can you please post as an answer?  To everyone who doesn't understand, let me see if I can explain.  If I do SELECT TOP 50 DISTINCT Name FROM TABLE it might have to go through 10,000,000 records which takes 3 hours.  If I do SELECT a.Name FROM (SELECT TOP 10000 * FROM TABLE) As a it won't take as long and will be reasonably accurate.

Comment: @ScottBeeson I understand what you're looking for and what its use-case is, I think, but it sounds like you already have it, don't you? Your last comment seems to answer the question, doesn't it?

Comment: Yes, as posted by @Lamak above.

Comment: Sql server can implement `top 50 distinct` without reading all rows (assuming there are 50 distinct values in the table) if there is a `hash match (flow distinct)` operator in the plan. Or if the column is indexed there are other ways.

Comment: While interesting, that could still potentially query a few million rows, which is what I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: But if it used an index, it might make a huge difference. Might not be as fast as `tablesample` but might be reasonably fast and would certainly be more accurate.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since you don't care what results you get, I reach for [tablesample](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189108%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) in these scenarios.

> You can use TABLESAMPLE to quickly return a sample from a large table when either of the following conditions is true:
>
> - The sample does not have to be a truly random sample at the level of individual rows.
> - Rows on individual pages of the table are not correlated with other rows on the same page.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    D.SomeValue
FROM
    dbo.MyTable AS D TABLESAMPLE(1000 ROWS);
```

What's going to happen is that the database engine is going to grab approximately 1k rows and then filter it. How it gets those rows doesn't matter because you don't care, you just want to take a peek at the unique values in that collection of data.

You might need to run that a few times. The first 3 runs against my 16M row table yielded no results.

And for more information on the no results issue, there's an excellent writeup 
[Sampling Using TABLESAMPLE](http://toponewithties.blogspot.co.uk/2005/08/sampling-using-tablesample.html) h/t to [Martin Smith](https://stackoverflow.com/users/73226/martin-smith)

Comment: What?  This is exactly what I wanted.  I don't know if I'm ecstatic or enraged!

Comment: I had no idea that `TABLESAMPLE` even existed; it's posts like these that always make me wonder what else I'm missing out on.

Comment: Nice solution! One question though, and it might be (read: probably is) me just misinterpreting: "The first 3 runs against my 16M table yielded no results". Does that mean: You got no distinct results (hrm), no results at all, not the results you were looking for or anything else completley?

Answer (score 5):

If the query is simple, with only 1 table in the `FROM` clause, you can simply change the `SELECT <columns>` to `SELECT TOP 100 <columns>` (note: **not** if it is a `DISTINCT`).

---

If the query is more complex, with multiple tables and/or a single table referenced multiple times, you can change one of the occurrence of the table you want to restrict, i.e. changing:

```
SELECT ...
FROM ...                   -- some tables
   <table_name> AS x
   ...                     -- some more joins
WHERE ...
... ;
```

to:

```
SELECT ...
FROM ...                   -- some tables
   ( SELECT TOP 100 *
     FROM <table_name>
     ORDER BY <some_columns>     -- without ORDER BY  if you don't care
                                 -- which 100 rows will be checked
   ) AS x
   ...                     -- some more joins
WHERE ...
... ;
```

---

Another approach, which will work with the simple case (whether it has `DISTINCT` or not) and if the query is more complex, with a table referenced multiple times and you want to restrict all the occurrences of that table:

```
WITH table_name AS
   ( SELECT TOP 100 *
     FROM <table_name>
     ORDER BY <some_columns>     -- without ORDER BY  if you don't care
                                 -- which 100 rows will be checked
   ) 
SELECT ...
--- your query unchanged ;
```

Comment: Thanks.  Waiting to see if @Lamak answers since he first proposed this solution in the comments.

Comment: @ScottBeeson Don't worry, wasn't really gonna answer and I couldn't post an answer as complete as this one anyway.

Answer (score 2):

If you want only the first 1,000 rows of a table, one possibility is [`TOP`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189463.aspx) as Lamak suggested:

```
select top 1000 * from MyTable
```

In the above query, `TOP` will return up to 1,000 rows in an undefined order.  If there are fewer than 1,000 rows, it will return the number of rows in the table.  If you need the top N using some kind of ordering, use an `ORDER BY`.

For example, the following query returns the top 1,000 rows from the *most recent* first:

```
select top 1000 * from MyTable order by EntryDate desc
```

Note that introducing an `ORDER BY` can cause an additional SORT operation.  You might want an index on that column if the table is very large.

If you control the client code, too, maybe you could implement this as a series of asynchronous calls to retrieve the next N distinct values.  Maybe N could be small at first and then widen up a bit if the user wants to sit and wait.  With an index, SQL Server should be able to perform this efficiently.

From the MSDN books online:

> Limits the rows returned in a query result set to a specified number
>   of rows or percentage of rows in SQL Server 2014. When TOP is used in
>   conjunction with the ORDER BY clause, the result set is limited to the
>   first N number of ordered rows; otherwise, it returns the first N
>   number of rows in an undefined order. Use this clause to specify the
>   number of rows returned from a SELECT statement or affected by an
>   INSERT, UPDATE, MERGE, or DELETE statement.

There are other ways, too.  If you want the top N of different criteria, you can use one of the [ranking functions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189798.aspx) like `ROW_NUMBER`, `RANK`, `DENSE_RANK`, or `NTILE`.

Comment: Copied from above comment, hope it makes sense: If I do SELECT TOP 50 DISTINCT Name FROM TABLE it might have to go through 10,000,000 records which takes 3 hours. If I do SELECT a.Name FROM (SELECT TOP 10000 * FROM TABLE) As a it won't take as long and will be reasonably accurate.

Comment: Now ROW_NUMBER might be a helpful direction.  I could constrain based on that.  Thanks.

Comment: The challenge with the ranking functions is that you will still need to access the entire table to create your segments before you can filter them

Comment: The problem in your example is the `DISTINCT` operator.  The operation would first look at all rows, aggregate the distinct values, and then return the `TOP` N from that list.  That can be very slow if you have a huge table.  That is why `SELECT TOP 10000 * FROM TABLE` performs faster.